# Difference between RUN bash -c and open form of RUN

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Some Dockerfiles have

```
RUN bash -c "apt-get update -qq && ... \"
```

while others write without quotes like

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && ... \
```

What is the difference between these variants? Is one of them more preferable over another one?

Comment: The former is very silly. There's an implicit `sh -c`, so `RUN bash -c "..."` is `RUN sh -c "bash -c \"...\""`.

Comment: Mind, `RUN ["bash", "-c", "..."]` is not silly at all, but that's a different construct (one that implicitly disables the assumed `sh -c`).

Comment: There can be good reasons to use bash instead of sh -- sometimes you need a bash-only feature like `>(...)` or `<(...)` or `pipefail` or `globstar` or arrays or so forth -- but there's never a good reason to have Docker start sh to start bash instead of having docker just start bash directly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess you mean smth like `RUN bash -c "set -o pipefail curl -sSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash"`. Here we use pipeline and we want to `set -o pipefail`. Do I get you right?

Comment: You want a `;` before the `curl`, and also `curl | sh` is generally a horrible practice I would never endorse, but yes, that's an example of enabling `pipefail` before running a pipeline where you want its behavior (in this case, a failure of `curl` to cause the whole command to be considered failed).

Comment: Also, `bash -c "curl | bash"` is inefficient for the same reason `sh -c "bash -c \"curl | bash\""` is inefficient: you're starting more shells than you need. You can always `eval "$(curl ...)"` inside an existing shell instead of starting a new one (though feeding code you downloaded from the Internet straight into a shell interpreter is hard to stomach with my security hat on).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is `RUN bash -c ...` mandatory for using `set -o pipefail`? Couldn't we simply write `RUN set -o pipefail && ...`?

Comment: `RUN` uses `sh`, not bash. Bash-only features are not guaranteed to work (depends on which copy of `sh` the specific container you're starting provides; ones based on Debian-style images will have ash or dash)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So, `set -o pipefail` is bash-only feature while `sh` does not support it?

Comment: "Does not" would be better stated as "may not". `sh` is not a specific shell. It can be _any_ shell that implements the POSIX sh standard, and that standard does not require `pipefail`. That doesn't mean no copy of sh ever supports pipefail, it just means not every copy of sh supports pipefail.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Please collect all comments into a single answer and post and I'll accept it.

Comment: If I meant to write an answer, I would have done so. This was just a comment (and then a bunch of follow-up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just write `RUN apt-get update ...` without manually inserting a `sh -c` wrapper.

The `RUN`, `CMD`, and `ENTRYPOINT` directives all share the same syntax.  It's best documented for `ENTRYPOINT` but all three commands work the same way.  There are two ways to write commands for them: you can either provide a specific set of command words as a JSON array ([exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example)), or you can write a string and Docker will automatically wrap it `sh -c` ([shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example)).  For example:

```sh
# Create a directory with a space in its name
RUN mkdir "a directory"

# JSON-array form: each array element is a shell word
RUN ["ls", "-ld", "a directory"]

# String form: Docker provides a shell, so these two are equivalent
RUN ls -ld 'a directory'
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -ld 'a directory'"]
```

This makes your first form redundant: if you `RUN bash -c '...'`, it's a string, and Docker automatically wraps it in `sh -c`.  So you get in effect

```sh
# RUN bash -c '...'
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bash -c '...'"]
```

GNU bash has a number of extensions that are not POSIX-standard syntax and it's possible to run into trouble with these, particularly on an Alpine-based image where `/bin/sh` is a minimal shell from the BusyBox toolset.  I could see this as an attempt to force a shell command to run using bash rather than the default shell.  For most things that appear in Dockerfiles, they won't usually be so complex that they can't be easily rewritten in standard syntax.

```sh
# Needs bash for the non-standard `source` syntax
RUN bash -c 'source ./venv/bin/activate && pip list'

# But you can use the standard `.` instead
RUN . ./venv/bin/activate && pip list
```

If you *must* have bash interpreting `RUN` lines then I'd suggest using the [`SHELL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) directive to change the command that's used to interpret bare strings.

Style-wise, I also occasionally see JSON-array syntax that begins with an explicit `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "..."]`.  There's no reason to write this out; it's shorter and no less clear to use the string form.